# How to get Ragel EOF actions working

Tags: c, finite-automata, state-machine, ragel

I'm working with Ragel to evaluate FSAs, and I want to embed a user action that runs whenever my machine finishes testing the input. I need this action to run regardless of whether or not the machine ends in an accepting state or not. I have this modified example taken from the Ragel guide that illustrates what I'm going for:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

%%{
    machine foo;
    main := ( 'foo' | 'bar' ) 0 @{ res = 1; } $/{ finished = 1; };
}%%
%% write data;
int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    int cs, res = 0, finished = 0;
    if ( argc > 1 ) {
        char *p = argv[1];
        char *pe = p + strlen(p) + 1;
        char* eof = pe;
        %% write init;
        %% write exec;
    }

    printf("result = %i\n", res );
    printf("finished = %i\n", finished);

    return 0;
}
```

My goal for this example is for res to be 1 when the input is either 'foo' or 'bar', while finished is 1 no matter the input. I can't get this to work though - finished seems to be 1 when res is 1, and 0 when res is 0.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 3):

The eof action will take place when `p == pe == eof`. Another important thing is that when your state machine can't match **any** state, the state will go to error and the match will stop, which means you can never go to the end.

Let's see when you input `foo1`. When parsing to `o`, everything is ok. Howerver the next charactor `1` can't match any state you specify, so an error occurs. You can never meet the eof action. So the variable `res` and `finish` is both 0.

When you input `foo`, every thing is ok. The state can go to the end. So the eof action take place.

You can set the error action to see what happens:

```
%%{
    main := ( 'foo' | 'bar' ) 0 @{ res = 1; } $err{ printf("error : %c", fc);} $/{ finished = 1; };
}%%
```

And you may try this code to meet your needs:

```
%%{
    main := (( 'foo' | 'bar' ) 0 @{ res = 1; } | any* ) $/{ finished = 1; };
}%%
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
main := ( 
    'foo' 0 @2 @{ res = 1; } | 
    'bar' 0 @2 @{ res = 1; } |
    any*
    ) @{ finished = 1; };
```